# Include values with function delegate?

Tags: c#

This isn't exactly what I am doing, but its close enough. I have two delegates pointing to the same function.

```
var foo=new Func<string, string, dynamic, string>(f);
var bar=new Func<string, string, dynamic, string>(f);
```

foo is called by a group of threads (not just one thread). bar is called by a different group of threads.

One of the parameters the function needs to know is which group of threads it was called from.

I can make each thread when it invokes the function to tell it its group name (the threads know which group they belong to), but is there a way to pass the thread group name (a string) to the function itself when declaring foo and bar ?

So anytime a thread calls foo, the function f will know its called from the first group, and everytime a thread calls bar, the function f will know it was called from the second group ?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your question. If all you want to is print the thread name, then just call Thread.CurrentThread.Name  from within f.

Comment: I am sorry, I clarified my question after posting it. Its the thread "group", which is an arbitrary string passed to the thread when its launched.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
var foo = new Func<string, dynamic, string>((s,d) => f("123", s, d));
var bar = new Func<string, dynamic, string>((s,d) => f("456", s, d));
```

That way the constant is used only once during declaration of the delegates.

Comment: wow ! yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, wasn't expecting it was that straightforward. Thank you so much :)